# why sets in python giving output unorder way but all time follow the same rule 1st complex then -ve and +ve after that a-z order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, set

```
s1 = {True, "Earth", "Sky", 25, -6.555, 9-5j, 25, "Sky", 25}
```

o/p = {(9-5j), -6.555, 25, 'Earth', 'Sky', True}

```
s2 = {"hi", -2+5j, 60, -6}
```

o/p = {(-2+5j), -6, 60, 'hi'}

can anyone help why they follow that type of order

Comment: @TurePålsson thanks for your response yes the link can be answer but that I did not understand if anyone can clearly explain then it will be helpful

Comment: @TurePålsson That answer is about Python 2. And OP's output is from Python 3. So not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Set are unordered as they stores values in hash table. The sequence of values solemnly depends on the execution machine. I had executed the code got different results from yours.

https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/e8808c91-0a5b-4dff-9caf-1da0f8be2142

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCRdr.png)

---

Happy coding :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4982185/mohit-atul in your output print is mentioned for that is why it giving that type result but if you just execute s2 or s1 then you get what I get also and why is there the difference also when we mention print o/p is different and when we did not put print o/p is another, kindly explain.

Comment: Hi, I've executed in ubuntu python also, its giving different results everytime with other python instances for example.
` Python 3.7.12 (default, Mar 23 2022, 15:01:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s1 = {True, "Earth", "Sky", 25, -6.555, 9-5j, 25, "Sky", 25}
>>> s2 = {"hi", -2+5j, 60, -6}
>>> s1
**{True, 'Sky', 'Earth', (9-5j), 25, -6.5549999999999997}**
>>> s2
**{-6, 'hi', 60, (-2+5j)}** `